# syntax when saving a file using dropna().to_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

To delete lines in a `CSV file` that have empty cells - I use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data  = pd.read_csv("./test_1.csv", sep=";")
data.dropna()
data.dropna().to_csv("./test_2.csv", index=False, sep=";")
```

everything works fine, but I get a new `CSV file` with `incorrect data`:

what is highlighted in red squares

[image]

I get additional signs in the form of a `dot` and a `zero` `.0`.

Could you please tell me how do I get correct data without `.0`

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas represents numeric `NAs` as `NaNs` and therefore casts all of your `ints` as `floats` (python `int` doesn't have a `NaN` value, but `float` does).

If you are sure that you removed all `NAs`, just cast your columns/dfs to `int`:

```
data = data.astype(int)
```

If you want to have integers and NAs, use pandas nullable integer types such as `pd.Int64Dtype()`.

more on nullable integer types:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html